# video streaming

Tags: operating-system

i would like to know what are the processes running in our OS while streaming videos?

Comment: What OS what program is doing this?

Comment: Question is not clear, more information needed.

Comment: Do you want to use command-line tools?

Comment: no. Just want to know what all happens in the OS

Comment: Streaming videos as a server or a client?

Comment: Which Unix/Linux? What graphical user interface do you have? Ubuntu, for example has a System Monitor. *are you beginning to sense how important it is to provide as much information as possible with your question?*

Answer (score 0):

to watch all process on your system
use
 ps -ef

or if you want to see what system calls your program do
 
use 
 
strace 
info about strace:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace

lsof 
can show you all open files

Comment: ignore this ilang7 is quicker picking up on his/her typos than i am :)